# __stdcall typedef struct

Tags: c++, struct, typedef, stdcall

I am writing my first DLL in C++. Using `__declspec(dll_export)`, I am able to read it on Python and C++ using a C wrapper. But I want now to read it on C too, so I have to add now the `__stdcall` convention. But I don't know how to apply it to a `typedef struct`. For example:

**Projet.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Projet_inc.h"

class Projet // before, class _declspec(dll_export) Projet
{
public:
    Projet();
    ~Projet();

    int multiply(int arg1, int arg2);
    int result;
};
```

**Projet_inc.h**

```
#ifdef PROJET_EXPORTS
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define CALLCONV_API __stdcall // before, this line didn't exist

extern "C" // C wrapper
{
    typedef struct Projet Projet; // make the class opaque to the wrapper

    Projet* EXPORT CALLCONV_API cCreateObject(void);
    int EXPORT CALLCONV_API cMultiply(Projet* pDLLobject, int arg1, int arg2);
}
```

and **Projet.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Projet.h"

Projet::Projet() {}
Projet::~Projet() {}

int Projet::multiply(int arg1, int arg2) {
    result = arg1 * arg2;
    return result;
}

Projet* EXPORT CALLCONV_API  cCreateObject(void)
{
    return new Projet();
}

int EXPORT CALLCONV_API  cMultiply(Projet* pDLLtest, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    if (!pDLLtest)
        return 0;
    return pDLLtest->multiply(arg1, arg2);
}
```

On Visual Studio 2017, the compilation return (first lines) :

```
dir\projet_inc.h(11) : warning C4229: anachronisme utilisé : modificateurs de données ignorés
dir\projet_inc.h(13) :error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : '__declspec(dllimport)'
```

And MSDN told that for C2059 error, I have to check on the typedef struct first.

Comment: calling conventions apply to callable functions, not structs.

Comment: stdcall has nothing to do with interoperability between C and C++.

Comment: I agree to this but because without this it won't work, I tried this and forget to delete it before to post on SO :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export specifiers apply only to functions and variables. Calling convention specifiers apply only to functions. So type alias (C-style) should look like this:

```
typedef struct Projet_I2M Projet_I2M;
```

Export specification should be infront of declaration:

```
EXPORT Projet * CALLCONV_API cCreateObject(void);
```

You seem to intentionally export C interface so you should prevent C++ exceptions from crossing language boundary.

`extern "C"` is should be conditionally included:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I agree with this because it was what I understood but I still have the same error message.

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin I've updated my answer. `EXPORT` should be infront of return type.

Comment: I didn't think about place EXPORT and CALLCONV_API separately. Thanks. Do you know why Visual warns me that there is an inconsistant Dll linkage for all the functions of the C wrapper now ?

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin I don't know, but this question most likely has been asked already.